# Invalid Request trying to get Sharepoint Site resource by Path in Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a Site resource by path using the Rest Graph API as explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getbypath?view=graph-rest-1.0) and I'm getting an error message indicating:

> Provided identifier is malformed - site collection id is not valid

I'm able to access the SharePoint site through the browser accessing to this URL:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site name>
```

The endpoint I'm forming has the following shape:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<tenant>.sharepoint.com:/<site name>
```

I am able to successfully retrieve Site information by id but not by path. 
Here is a screenshot of how the request I'm trying to make looks like in Postman.

[image: Postman GraphApi request]

This is the response when getting site information by id:

[image]

Is the endpoint URL correctly formed for retrieving the site resource information?

Comment: Could you add the results you're getting from the site by id? The site name would also be helpful.

Comment: I've added the response I get by Id. Sorry, it is mostly covered, I can't disclose any detail about the client.

Answer (score 1):

When addressing [sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0) by path, the format as follows:

> SharePoint hostname, followed by a colon and the *relative path to the
>   site*

It appears in your example site name specified instead of relative site path:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<tenant>.sharepoint.com:/<site name>
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^ 
                                                      should refer to relative path to the site
```

instead it should be like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<tenant>.sharepoint.com:/sites/<site name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i tested this endpoint and am able to get site resource.

Site URL:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}
```

Get a site resource by path:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenant}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{sitename}
```

result:
[call endpoint through MS graph explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1s3r.png)

thanks